# AngularJS - $cancelRequest not available in $resource

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource

I am trying to fire abort request however, I am not getting `$cancelRequest` object in result of `$resource`. But, I am able to get `$promise` and `$resolved` objects.

Why is this happening? How can I get this `$cancelRequest` ?

PS: I'm using AngularJS 1.5

**UPDATE**: After some trial and errors I found that it was not working just because I was using AngularJS 1.5 rc 0. Now when I used AngularJS 1.5 rc 2. which is the current latest, it just worked.

Answer (score 9):

According to documentation, it is only available for [Angular 1.5](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) :

> $cancelRequest: If there is a cancellable, pending request related to the instance or collection, calling this method will abort the request.

I cannot see any mention of it on [Angular 1.4](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/docs/api/ngResource/service/$resource)...

I can only suggest you to update to 1.5 version but it is still an rc-1 version...

To enable it, you have to configure $resource, by default, it is disable :

> Hash with custom settings that should extend the default
>   $resourceProvider behavior. The supported options are:
>
> stripTrailingSlashes – {boolean} – If true then the trailing slashes
>   from any calculated URL will be stripped. (Defaults to true.)
>   cancellable – {boolean} – If true, the request made by a
>   "non-instance" call will be cancelled (if not already completed) by
>   calling $cancelRequest() on the call's return value. This can be
>   overwritten per action. (Defaults to false.)

Working with this code

```
<html ng-app="test">
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.1/angular-resource.min.js"></script>

<script>
angular.module('test', ['ngResource'])
.config(function($resourceProvider) {
    $resourceProvider.defaults.cancellable = true;
})
.factory('Resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('api/test', {}, {
        test: { cancellable : true }
    });
})
.controller('myController', function($scope, Resource) {
    Resource.query().$cancelRequest(); // ok 
    Resource.test().$cancelRequest(); // ok
});

</script>

</head>
<body ng-controller="myController">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using AngularJS 1.5. But even in AngularJS 1.5 I'm not getting `$cancelRequest`

Comment: According to documentation, you have to set 'cancelable' to true to enable $cancelRequest : cancellable – {boolean} – if set to true, the request made by a "non-instance" call will be cancelled (if not already completed) by calling $cancelRequest() on the call's return value. Calling $cancelRequest() for a non-cancellable or an already completed/cancelled request will have no effect.

Comment: I had `cancellable :true` already in place but the results dont change

Comment: I just edit my answer. I created a dummy file to check and it works fine for me. Hope it will help you.

Comment: After some trial and errors I found that it was not working just because I was using AngularJS 1.5 rc 0. Now when I used AngularJS 1.5 rc 2. which is the current latest, it just worked. Appreciate your help @Yoann :)